# Remove customize last line from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, mismatch

I have a ListView which contains number of TextViews and a custom footer border. I want the last line of the ListView gone.

I have tried something like this:

```java
if (position == arrayList.size() - 1) {
    viewHolder.lineSeperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

It is working but when I scroll the ListView, the line position is changed and mismatched. How do I fix that?

### activity_main.xml

```xml
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imgFooter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearRow"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:listitem="@layout/my_row" />
```

### my_row.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgProfile"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.example.ui.widget.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.example.ui.widget.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtType"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.example.ui.widget.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtManager"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.example.ui.widget.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.mawthouq.ui.widget.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTotalRow"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    customFont:fontTextStyle="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lineSeperator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearRow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />
```

Comment: what you mean by custom last line ?? can you provide any screenshot ??

Comment: Thanks but I got the answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add the else case, try this and see if it works:

```
if (position == arrayList.size() - 1) {
    viewHolder.lineSeperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
    viewHolder.lineSeperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get Last Position in an ArrayList using,

```
int LastPos = arrayList.size() - 1;
```

then put,

```
if (position == LastPos) {
viewHolder.lineSeperator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
viewHolder.lineSeperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

to your **Adapter Class**.